# Why do I see 20 nodes in YARN but 30 workers in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I spun up 30 AWS machines.

When I check YARN UI at the master node's ip `8088`, I click on "Nodes" and I can see the following:

- under "Active Nodes" I see 20
- under "Lost Nodes" I see 0.

I navigate to the spark master at port `18080` I can see that pyspark is telling me that `Alive Workers: 30`.  At beginning of page.

I restarted all of services on master node and slaves but still same thing happening.

How I get YARN to recognize all of nodes?

Comment: What is your spark.executor.instances setting? Or are you passing any num-executors value while submitting job?

Answer (score 1):

Check your datanode by below command on your namenode,

```
sudo yarn node -list -all
```

and if you can't find all 30 nodes, do below command on your misssing datanode,

```
sudo service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager start
```

and do below command on your namenode,

```
sudo service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager restart
```

Or, check `/etc/hadoop/conf/slaves` in your namenode,

and check below setting in `/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml` of all your nodes

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>your namenode name</value>
</property>
```

Or, write your all nodes' names and ipadress in all nodes' `/etc/hosts`
for example,

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.1.10 test1
192.168.1.20 test2
```

and you have to do the command,

`/etc/rc.d/init.d/network reload`

Comment: Interesting that there are three options for this solution....The last one seems the easiest.  I tried simply adding the names and ip addresses to the `/etc/hosts` file, but that didn't change anything.  Do I have to restart any of the services after I change that file?  
Maybe the `spark-worker` service?  or the `spark-master` service?  or `hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager` service?

Comment: So I do not have to restart any of the spark services?  `spark-worker` or `spark-master`?

Comment: If not, why not?

Comment: you should fix files of both 'spark-worker' and 'spark-master'. If you fix files, the servers containing the files have to restart.